# How do you declare non-commutable variables in julia?

Tags: julia

How do you define non-commutable variables? I'm new to julia and have been reading the doc and found nothing so far.

By non-commutable I mean if variables (say symbols) a and b are multiplied. a*b =\= b*a

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you mean? Immutable (const) variables?

Comment: @ToivoHenningsson I have edited -- but I mean if variables (say symbols) a and b are multiplied. a*b =\= b*a

Comment: What language let's you say that? Prolog?

Comment: @stefankarpinski python did, it had a full symbol library. I was under the impression julia may be similar since it's so widly used for computational programming

Comment: When you define your own type, you can also define the `*` operator: it is not assumed to be commutative. For instance, for strings or matrices, it is not commutative (it is not defined for symbols: the product of two symbols is no longer a symbol, but would be an expression).

If, instead of defining your own types, you want to play with ASTs (e.g., `:(x * y)`),
you can read the 
[metaprogramming](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/) section of the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About commutativity: Julia does not assume that `a*b` is the same as `b*a` (example: let `a` and `b` be matrices). However, methods of the function `*(a,b)` for some specific combinations of types act in a commutative manner, such as when `a` and `b` are numbers.

Since you are talking about symbols, I guess that want to work with a symbolic representation of expressions. There's at least two ways to go about this:

1. Work with the AST of an expression.
   You can quote any expression by `:(expr)` (sometimes `:expr` is enough, depends on operator precedence):

   ```
   julia> ex = :(x*y*z)
   :(x * y * z)

   julia> typeof(ex)
   Expr
   ```

   Note that the order of the factors has been preserved (though the associativity has not).
   You can inspect the `Expr` by looking at it's `head` and `args` fields:

   ```
   julia> ex.head
   :call

   julia> ex.args
   4-element Array{Any,1}:
    :*
    :x
    :y
    :z
   ```

   The args may be e.g. symbols (of type `Symbol`), constant values, and other expressions.
   This technique works well if you want to write your own macros that process expressions, since the input to a macro is the AST of its arguments.
2. Define your own types and overload the `*` function. Example: with

   ```
   abstract Symbolic

    # might as well make these immutable
   immutable Sym <: Symbolic
       name::Symbol
   end

   immutable Prod <: Symbolic
       x::Symbolic
       y::Symbolic
   end

   # The * function is imported by default.
   # Usually, we need to import a function
   # from Base before extending it.
   *(x::Symbolic, y::Symbolic) = Prod(x, y)
   ```

   you can do

   ```
   julia> x, y = Sym(:x), Sym(:y)
   (Sym(:x),Sym(:y))

   julia> x*y
   Prod(Sym(:x),Sym(:y))
   ```

   Since our `*(x::Symbolic, y::Symbolic)` function preserves the order of the arguments, we can see it in the created `Prod` object.

In most languages, the second alternative is your only option. The first alternative is more direct since you don't have to write a new AST framework for yourself, and don't have to execute the expression just to get at it's representation. Which one is more suitable depends on the application, however. If you want to associate different properties with your variables, the second approach seems easier.

Was it something like this that you were looking for?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I didn't know how in-depth I needed to know since in python its simply a 'commutative = false' or 'commutative = true' term.